# How to rsync web repo

Tags: rsync

I want to rsync everything in mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/ to a directory on my server.  I do NOT want to wind up with a directory structure like ~/mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/

```
[joliver@lake ~]$ rsync mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/ CentOS6/
rsync: change_dir "/home/joliver/mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]
[joliver@lake ~]$ mkdir -p mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages
[joliver@lake ~]$ rsync mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/ mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages
skipping directory .[joliver@lake ~]$ rsync mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/ mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/
skipping directory .
```

After I have that, I'd like to be able to rsync just the deltas.  I suppose just redoing the rsync and then finding all files with a ctime of less that since the last run would suffice, but it would be nice if there was a neater way to grab new / changed files.

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -avSHP --delete --exclude "local*" --exclude "isos" \ 
  mirrors.kernel.org::centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/ CentOS6/
```